# Prove the divergence of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I prove that $$(2+(-2)^n)$$ diverges?

Is it as simple as saying, that the sequence oscillates between positive and negative numbers for even and odd values of n respectively, so therefore it does not converge. Hence it is divergent?

Comment: Well, technically a sequence _could_ oscillate and still be convergent (converging to $0$). You would have to point out that for $n>1$ the sequence is also increasing in absolute value, so it couldn't converge to $0$.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter - The question is about a sequence, not a series.

Comment: @uniquesolution I glanced over the poor formatting initially.

Comment: @Arthur Yes i see what you mean about converging to 0! How would i go about showing it is divergent though?

Comment: @uniquesolution The point that lim inf and lim sup disagree still holds.

Comment: @Anthony Peter, yes, it does.

Answer (score 1):

If the sequence $(2 + (-2)^n)$ converges, then every subsequence should converge and have the same limit. The subsequence of even terms $(2 + (-2)^{2n})$ tends to $+\infty$, so the sequence $(-2 + (-2)^n)$ doesn't converge.

Answer (score 0):

I can say that a Cauchy sequence is always convergent and vice-versa. So if a sequence is non-Cauchy, then it must, from above, hold that the sequence is not convergent i.e. divergent.
 So, for Cauchy sequence, it holds that $$ \text{there exists} \,\ N_0 \in N \,\ \text{such that} \,\ |x_m-x_n|<\epsilon \,\ \text{for some} \,\ m,n \ge N_0 \,\ \text{and} \,\ \epsilon > 0$$
To prove that $|x_m-x_n|>\epsilon \,\ \text{for} \,\ \epsilon > 0$ 
Take m = n+1
$$|x_{n+1}-x_n|=|[2+(-2)^{n+1}]-[2+(-2)^n]|$$ 
$$=|(-2)^{n+1}-(-2)^n| $$
$$=|(-2)^n(-2-1)|$$
$$=3\cdot 2^n \cdot |(-1)^n|$$
$$=3\cdot 2^n > \epsilon \,\ \forall \,\ \epsilon > 0 \,\ \text{and} \,\ N_0 \in N$$
Hence we can conclude that $$ \text{there exists no} \,\ N_0 \in N \,\ \text{such that} \,\ |x_m-x_n|<\epsilon \,\ \text{for some} \,\ m,n \ge N_0 \,\ \text{and} \,\ \epsilon > 0$$ that is, in other words, $$\forall \,\ N_0 \in N \,\ |x_m-x_n|>\epsilon \,\ \text{for any} \,\ m,n \ge N_0 \,\ \text{and} \,\  \epsilon > 0$$
So I can conclude that $x_n = 2+(-2)^n$ is divergent.